# Why variable does not take negative value in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mat

I'm new to Matlab.
I have these simple lines. The problem is that the *sum* variable does not take negative values. All variables are double.

```
 Inp_pixel = Inp_padded(x, y);
 Filter_pixel = Filter(f_row, f_col);
 sum = sum + (Inp_pixel * Filter_pixel);
```

for example: if *Filter_pixel* = -1 and *Inp_pixel* = 150 and *sum* = 0. the expected result should be -150 but I get *sum* = 0

Comment: I get **all** negative values!!! But then, I had to make up values for `Inp_padded`, `x`, `y`, `Filter`, `f_row`, `f_col`, and `sum` and I'm notorious for picking the wrong values.

Comment: more clarification please.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? if you can't describe your problem clear enough, it is hard for other people to guess what you want to do and help you out.

Comment: my problem is in the SUM variable. it ignores the negative values.

Comment: more clarification please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in *Inp_pixel*. This variable assigned from an *uint8* 2D array.
that's why this variable didn't take the negative value of the multiplication. I used *cast()* function to solve this problem.
for more details about this function please check this link.
[MATLAB documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cast.html)